# Failed to change a data frame column name

Tags: r

I have below data frame.

```
> head(weather)
V6   V7    V8          V9      V10     V11
1                                            
2                                            
3                                            
4 Day Hour Value        Unit Duration QC Name
5   1    0   231 \xb5g/m\xb3     1 Hr   Valid
6   1    1   239 \xb5g/m\xb3     1 Hr   Valid
```

the firs three rows are empty and the column name is `V6` to `V11`. I want to use the fourth line as the column name. I tried below method but it doesn't work.

```
colnames(weather) <- weather[4,]
```

after run above command, my column name becomes:

```
> colnames(weather)
[1] "33"  "26"  "427" "3"   "3"   "3"
```

I don't know where these values come from. How can I update the column name in my data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the class of the columns.  It could be `factor` when it gets coerced toe `integer` storage mode.  This can be rectified in its root by reading with `skip` argument

```
weather <- read.csv("yourfile.csv", skip=4, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

If we are using the OP's method, then `unlist` the row and convert to `character`

```
colnames(weather) <- as.character(unlist(weather[4,]))
```